# This for loop won't draw rectangles, but will write to console

Tags: java, for-loop, processing, rect

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        noStroke();
        fill(50,50,50);
        rect(0,0,100,100,i);
        System.out.println(i);
        delay(100);
    }
```

This is the for loop, it will write the numbers 0 to 50, and then draw a rectangle. The goal is to have it draw rectangles with an increasing radius on the corners. It does not do the rect(), but does do the System.out.println();. This is written in java processing.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] instead of a disconnected snippet?

Comment: Could it be because you're unable to discern the difference in radii because of the fill color ?

Comment: `public void setup() {
 }
 
 public void settings(){
  size(800,600);
 }

 public void draw() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
   stroke(100,0,0);
   fill(50,50,50);
   rect(0,0,100,100,i);
   System.out.println(i);
   delay(100);
  }
 }` I changed it to this and it is still not working as expected, only drawing one rectangle as it finishes the loop.

Comment: it almost seems like it is drawing all of the rectangles at the same time, instead of waiting a tenth of second between drawing them.

Comment: @ByronLathi Please see my answer. I explain exactly why that's happening.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question. It turns out that it already is an [mcve], even without a `draw()` function. Please note that this is a [tag:processing] question, not a Java question, and [Processing != Java](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java).

Comment: @RyanBemrose Can you see my note on reopening this question?

Comment: @EbbeMPederson Can you see my note on reopening this question?

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili Can you see my note on reopening this question?

Comment: @HarshalPatil Can you see my note on reopening this question?

Comment: @alexanderpolomodov Can you see my note on reopening this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `delay()` function to create animations.

Nothing will draw to the screen until the `draw()` function finishes (or if you're not using a `draw()` function, until the code ends). Everything is drawn to an off-screen buffer, and then the buffer is drawn to the screen all at one time when the `draw()` function finishes.

So really you're drawing a rectangle to the off-screen buffer, waiting 100 ms, drawing another rectangle to the off-screen buffer, waiting 100 ms, drawing another rectangle, and so on. You won't actually see anything on the screen until after all of that waiting completes.

If you want to create an animation, don't use a loop. Instead, use the `draw()` function along with a sketch-level variable that you increment (or just use the predefined `frameCount` variable).

Another problem is that you're just drawing the same color rectangle over and over again. You're drawing a gray rectangle, and then a slightly smaller gray rectangle on top of it, and then a slightly smaller rectangle on top of it, and so on. So you'll never actually see the smaller rectangles, since they blend in to the first rectangle you're drawing.

Run this program to better understand what's going on:

```
noStroke();
fill(50,50,50);
rect(0,0,100,100,0);
fill(255, 0, 0);
rect(0,0,100,100,10);
fill(0, 255, 0);
rect(0,0,100,100,20);
```

Comment: thank you, I was unaware that the draw() function worked that way.

Comment: @ByronLathi No problem. The `draw()` function works this way because Processing uses something called [double buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics) which helps prevent problems like flickering or tearing. If it didn't work this way, things would get pretty ugly!